# Abrir aplicação externa como sendo um form filho em C#

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

Estou precisando fazer a chamada de um aplicativo externo pela minha aplicação atual, no qual este aplicativo externo estar sendo aberto fora da minha aplicação e gostaria que fosse aberto como sendo um form filho do meu form pai. Este é o meu código atual que estar abrindo este aplicativo de forma independe da aplicação:

```
private void buttonBoletos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string diretorio = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
                string caminho = Path.Combine(diretorio, "Boleto.exe");

                Process process = Process.Start(caminho , "GBSODETO");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Aplicativo não encontrado: \"" + ex.Message + "\"", "Atenção!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando a API Win32 é possível "comer" outro software. Basicamente você abre esse aplicativo e coloca-se que o "pai" dele é o `panel` que você quer trabalhar. Se você não quiser que o "efeito de estilo" de MDI você tem que ajustar o estilo da janela de forma que fique maximizado e remover a barra de título.

Veja um exemplo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process p = Process.Start("notepad.exe");
            p.WaitForInputIdle(); // Tempo de espera para que a janela do aplicativo "apareça"
            SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, panel1.Handle); // Aqui está a jogada, colocando o panel "pai"
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
    }
}
```